# Some mean value limiting result

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, estimation

Let $\phi$ be continuous in a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbf{R}^3$ (you may assume it to be uniformly continuous, if you like). Do we have that
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon^2}\int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)}\phi \ do=\phi(0)?$$
My "proof" would be to write
$$\left|\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon^2}\int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)}\phi-\phi(0) \ do\right|\leq\sup_{x\in\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\left|\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right|\stackrel{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$ but does this last limit even hold? Under which circumstances would it be true?

This result is used in proving $1/4\pi r$ to be a fundamental solution of $-\Delta$.

Comment: This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Though your question can't be answered directly from the LDT

Comment: this is known to me already

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbf{R}^n$ and not $\mathbf{R}^3$? Your surface area is that of the 3D-sphere...

Comment: oh sorry, $R^3$

Comment: Continuity is sufficient, and the proof goes like you think.

Comment: @DanielFischer: thanks, nice to hear! but I am a bit concernd about the sup. Could clarify to me how this follows from continuity? I hope it is not too embarissingly direct from the definition, if it is please say so

Comment: The continuity says that for every $\eta > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\lVert x-0\rVert < \delta$ we have $\lvert \phi(x) - \phi(0)\rvert <\eta$. Choose $\varepsilon < \delta$, and you get $$\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon^2} \left\lvert \int_{\lVert x\rVert = \varepsilon} \phi(x) - \phi(0)\,do\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon^2} \int_{\lVert x\rVert=\varepsilon} \lvert \phi(x)-\phi(0)\rvert\,do\leqslant \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon^2} \int_{\lVert x\rVert=\varepsilon} \eta\,do = \eta.$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you could post it as an answer and I will accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works well. Under the sole assumption that $\phi$ is integrable over the sphere, we have

$$\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon^2}\left\lvert \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)} \phi(x) - \phi(0)\,do \right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon^2}\int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)} \lvert \phi(x)-\phi(0)\rvert\,do \leqslant \sup_{x\in\partial B_\varepsilon(0)} \lvert \phi(x) - \phi(0)\rvert.$$

If $\phi$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $0$, then $\phi$ is integrable over all small enough spheres, and

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \sup_{x\in\partial B_\varepsilon(0)} \lvert \phi(x) - \phi(0)\rvert = 0$$

is a direct consequence of the continuity in $0$.